# Animate position of a widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to animate the position of an icon widget on the screen. The problem is that I don't know the end position of widget until the whole screen has finished building.

This sketch illustrates what I want to achieve:
[image]

The icon should start out from the centre of the screen and end up in middle of the space available above the text field and button. The text field and the button themselves are centred in the screen.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can be achieved using a Hero animation. If I wrap and tag the icon widgets with a Hero widgets in both screens, the icon will automatically be animated when the screen is transitioned using a navigator.

Answer (score 3):

I've updated the code since I didn't fully understand your question before.

Here's the updated code on dartpad.dev so you can see how it looks and works:
https://dartpad.dev/74043837eaa459089fae03449fdc0778

And here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: LoginWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginWidgetState createState() => _LoginWidgetState();
}

class _LoginWidgetState extends State<LoginWidget> {
  @override
  initState() {
    initialTimer();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    super.initState();
  }

  GlobalKey _keyRed = GlobalKey();

  var gotPosition = false;
  var redPositionX;
  var redPositionY;
  var redWidth;
  var redHeight;

  _afterLayout(_) {
    _getPositions();
    _getSizes();
    setState(() {
      gotPosition = true;
    });
  }

  _getSizes() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final sizeRed = renderBoxRed.size;
    print("SIZE of Red: $sizeRed");
    redWidth = sizeRed.width;
    redHeight = sizeRed.height;
  }

  _getPositions() {
    print("beer");
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    print(renderBoxRed);
    final positionRed = renderBoxRed.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    print("POSITION of Red: $positionRed ");
    redPositionY = positionRed.dy;
    redPositionX = positionRed.dx;
  }

  var startAnimation = false;
  initialTimer() async {
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    setState(() {
      startAnimation = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    print('width/height $screenWidth / $screenHeight');

    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth * 0.3),
                  key: _keyRed,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                  height: screenHeight * 0.2,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        width: screenWidth * 0.3,
                        height: screenHeight * 0.05,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        width: screenWidth * 0.3,
                        height: screenHeight * 0.05,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // ),
              ],
            ),
            AnimatedPositioned(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              top: startAnimation
                  ? ((redPositionY / 2) - (redHeight / 2))
                  : redPositionY,
              curve: Curves.easeInCubic,
              left: 0.3 * screenWidth,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: screenWidth * 0.4,
                    height: screenHeight * 0.2,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Differences and explanation:

In this version, I made it as responsive as possible, and was able to use a global key in order to select the red box and get it's position and size. At the end of render time, it invokes _afterLayout() that updates the information for the animation, so that it starts on the red box, and finishes halfway up. (using the data from the size and position of the red box.)

This was new to me, so I relied on this tutorial here:
https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407 in order to get a feel for how to approach getting size and position of a widget as well as how to manage running the code at the end of render.

Comment: I know how animate widgets when their start and end positions are known beforehand. The question is how to animate a widget whose end position is determined by the layout. F.e in this case the icon is a child of an Expanded widget, which is a child of the Column widget.

Comment: Do you have any example code? I’m imagining this is driven by a responsive requirement, yes? Have You tried using a percentage of a Mediaquery.of(context).height call as the initial and final positions (as well as the height of the object as well)

Comment: Now that I understand your question a little bit better, I'm trying to update my code.  I was specifically looking at this: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407 where you define a global key to use to get the position of a widget after layout is down.  Then, (I hope) this position can be used in the animation.

Comment: The best way to achieve this seems to be Hero animations. I can tag two widgets in completely different layouts and have them automatically animate when I transition from the first screen to the second.

Comment: I went ahead and did it with direct control.  I'm about to update my answer.  I think the Hero should work as well... you just won't have as much control over the animation. (but hey, if it works, it works!)

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue though. This solution requires a Stack and the end position is still fixed to some location on the screen. I need the final position to depend on the layout and not be hard coded.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer for the effort, but this is still very much hard coding it. Firstly since it's using Stack, the elements will start overlapping each other when the screen height gets too small (f.e when the soft-keyboard opens). Secondly if the layout of the 2nd screen changes you have to completely redo your calculations. Thirdly if the layout gets even a little more complex the necessary calculations would skyrocket (f.e the designer adds centred a text under the icon). There is no reason to choose this direction over Hero animations (which can also be customized).

Comment: Interesting. I’ll keep that in mind for next time. thanks for the upvote!